# One of my Dell Monitor becomes Synaptic Inc 24'' on Ubuntu 18

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell

please excuse me if I did not post this question on the right website since I'm not sure this issue is caused by Dell or Ubuntu.

I have Dell laptop (Precision5530) running Ubuntu 18. I have 2 external monitors (let's call it number 3 and number 2) connected to it and they were working fine. I unplugged the number 2 monitor to connect to a Mac for a while and then plugged it back to the Dell laptop. However, the number 2 monitor becomes "stretched". It looks like a small display been stretched to a large display. I checked the Display setting on Ubuntu and saw that the number 2 monitor's name becomes  `Synaptic Inc 24''` which was original `Dell Inc 23''`. I'm not sure why it happens. I did a factory reset on the monitor and rebooting the laptop but none of these fixed the issue.

FYI the 2 monitors are connected to the laptop via a dock.

[Screen shot of Display setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfo1C.png)

Comment: Do you mean 18.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 18?  (it's usually used headless but can use GNOME which is packaged as a snap, is that what you're doing?)